# FuncAnimation only draws last frame in saved .mp4 file

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, save

I have a Visualization class, which is visualizing a Lockbox using matplotlib. 
After each iteration the configuration of the lockbox changes and the visualization's update methode is called and all mechanisms are drawn again. After each iteration I get a new axis objects. Displaying them during run time works fine, but when I store the axis objects in a list and try to make an animation out of it later, after saving I get a movie with only the last frame being shown for 20 seconds (100 Frames, 200ms intervall).
Most questions I found had the problem of not specifically assigning the animation object but I'm doing this already. It doesn't matter if I use ipython or just execute the code from the shell with python.
Unfortunately it's not possible to give a working example to replicate it. Maybe you have an idea what is wrong, anyway. Thanks!

```
    def init_grid(self,lockbox):
        '''Create the figure objects and the grid'''
        self.size = lockbox.size
        self.square_width = lockbox.square_width
        self.door_idx = lockbox.find_door()
        w = self.size[0]*self.square_width + 0.001
        h = self.size[1]*self.square_width + 0.001

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
        self.ax.set_title('Lockbox')
        self.ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,w,52.5))
        self.ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,h,52.5))
        self.ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)

    def update(self, grid, idx_mech):
        '''Deletes all rectangles and draws the new configuration of mechanisms'''
        self.history.append(self.ax)
        #Removing all rectangles
        [p.remove() for p in reversed(self.ax.patches)]
        #Draw new rectangles
        self.draw_mechanisms(grid, idx_mech)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.1)

    def save_animation(self):
        '''Saves the current simulation to animation.mp4'''
        self.history.append(self.ax)
        anima = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, frames = len(self.history), blit=False)
        #plt.show() here only shows the last frame as well.
        anima.save('animation.mp4')

    def animate(self,i):
        return self.history[i]
```